# Take average value of masked array along specific axis in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, mask

I am trying to average a region of a 3 dimensional array specified by a mask array in matlab. This is fairly straightforward to accomplish in python.

```
import numpy

array = numpy.arange(27).reshape(3,3,3)
mask = numpy.array( [ 
                        [1,0,1],
                        [0,1,0],
                        [1,0,1]
                        ], dtype=bool )

array[mask] = array[mask].mean(0)
```

Translating the syntax to matlab results in an error, as masking does not seem to work the same way

```
array = reshape(1:27, 3,3,3);
mask = [true,false,true;false,true,false;true,false,true];
array(mask) = mean( array(mask), 0 )
```

I have tried a number of different things to get this to work, but have not had any success. I have found a few answers to similar questions on mathworks, they tend to use operations that are entirely unfamiliar to me and I'm not able to understand them well enough to implement them.

Comment: What is the error you get when running it in MATLAB?

Comment: How does mask array look like in python? Could you give an example?